# absolute value of difference between 2 chars in ASCII table without "abs" or "if"

Tags: c, getchar, putchar

this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
  void main() {
        char a, b;
        char c;
        printf("enter 2 chars: ");
        a = getchar();
        b = getchar();
        c = a - b;
        printf("%d",c );
  }
```

I'm trying to find the absolute value between two chars, for example, 'A'&'a'=>32
'a'&'A'=>32
my code shows negative answer,what should I do without using abs function or if, I tried this:

```
printf("%u",c );
```

but it gives me 4294967264. is there any **simple** way to do it? it should use getchar and putchar!

Comment: Unless you are on a freestanding environment, `void main()` is an invalid signature and invokes undefined behaviour. On typical PC OS Like MacOS, Win or Linux, the minimal signature is `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without branching: (assumes two's complement integer representation)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter 2 chars: ");
    char a = getchar();
    char b = getchar();
    char c = a - b;

    c = (c^-(c < 0)) + (c < 0);

    printf("%d\n", c);
}
```

Split in pieces:

`(c < 0)` gives `0` when `c` is positive:
`c = (c^-0) + 0` ~> `c = c^0` ... $foo XOR 0 gives $foo
`c = c` nothing to do.

`(c < 0)` gives `1` when `c` is negative:
`c = (c^-1) + 1` ... `-1` in two's complement is all bits set (`~0`)
`c = (c^(~0)) + 1` ... a negative `c` in two's complement XOR `~0` gives `-c - 1`
 
`c = -c - 1 + 1` ~> `c = -c`

gcc 8.3 -O3: (cl v15.9.0-pre.3.0 produces equivalent assembly)

```
mov     edx, edi    ; edx = c
shr     edx, 31     ; right shift, keep only the sign bit (c < 0) [sign]
mov     eax, edx    ; eax =  [sign]
neg     eax         ; eax = -[sign]
xor     eax, edi    ; eax = -[sign] xor c
add     eax, edx    ; eax += [sign]
```

Comment: can you explain this line? c = (c ^ - (c < 0)) + (c < 0);

Comment: `c < 0` may cause branching.  IAC, "Without branching:" was not explicitly requested by OP. Code relies on the very common, though not required, 2's complement for correct functionality.

Comment: @chux *was not explicitly requested by OP.* – no, but thats one of the reasons to do something without if ^^

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use the abs function.

```
printf("%d",abs(c) );
```

But if you do not want to use it, you can try change the line:

```
c = a - b;
```

to:

```
c = (a > b) ? (a-b) : (b - a);
```

Comment: this actually worked for me! it's the same as using if.

Comment: @MajdSadi Because you said *without `if`* in your question I was under the impression that you wanted to avoid branching.

Comment: OP requests `without "abs" or "if"` yet this answer contains both (`?:` operator is equivalent to `if` statement)

Comment: @user2162550: so you agree that this answer is correct on the `?:`, right? It is clearly not an `if`, it is an *equivalent*. Just as "add two numbers *x*, *y* without using `+`" can be answered with `x--y`. This is an *equivalent* but not the literal use, and so totally legit.

Comment: so maybe you should explain clearly what you want in the problem description, since ':?' is one option and 'if' is another one.

Comment: `?:` and `if` will probably lead to same machine code, yet `c=  (c^-(c < 0)) + (c < 0)` and `c = (a > b) ? (a-b) : (b - a)` is less likely to lead to same machine code, so saying that `?:` is not `if` is just being naive, but anyway, answer still contains "abs". Swordfish's answer much more acceptable

Comment: I'm not saying that both lead to different machine code. This is why you should better explain exactly what you want. When you say: "without using if", we assume that you want to avoid using new lines from if statement.

Comment: I'm not the one who wrote the post

Comment: so write your own suggestion code to help the user instead of being a judge.

Comment: @AndersonOliveira Usually, usage of the ternary operator should be avoided when possible, since it is much less readable than an if-statement. Saving line numbers is also not an argument, because `if(c < 0) c = -c;` can easily and readable be written in one line and is also shorter than `c = c < 0 ? -c : c;`. Doing something without if makes most sense when performance is critical and one wants to avoid a conditional jump.

Comment: @Swordfish, "if" option, as you described, is not  shorter than "?:" because it does not have the else option, so you would need new command line to work it using "if".

Comment: @AndersonOliveira the "else part" of the ternary op is self-assignment which has no effect.

Comment: correct, so you need two lines: 1) c = a - b; 2) if(c < 0) c = -c; 
as I said before, I supose the user want avoid lines, and with the another option you have c = (a > b) ? (a-b) : (b - a);

Comment: @AndersonOliveira No, I don't. I can write them both in one line :p

Comment: I can put multiple commands in a single line, but it would be inelegant.